# Multi collectItems how to early terminate and return the collected items

Tags: java, streaming, quarkus, mutiny

In my quarkus service, i am building [a custom accumulator](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/collecting-items#using-a-custom-accumulator) to consume a `Multi`. The stream can potentially be infinite, and I wonder how to early terminate and collect the results when sufficient data has been accumulated?

Below are my prototype:

```
Multi<Data> sortedStream = getStream();
return this.sortedStream.collectItems().in(
    LinkedList::new,
    new BiConsumer<LinkedList<Coverage>, Data>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(LinkedList<Coverage> coverages, Data incoming) {
        if (coverages.isEmpty()) {
            coverages.add(new Coverage(incoming));
            return;
        }

        if (enough(coverages)) {
            // Question: How to early terminate and collect coverage downstream?
        }

        Coverage last = coverages.getLast();
        if (worthAdd(last, incoming)) {
            coverages.add(new Coverage(incoming));
        } else {
            return;
        }

        }
    }
)
```

Comment: I note that the link says  _Don’t collect items from infinite streams or you will likely end with an out-of-memory failure!_ so if you limit the stream somehow upstream so it'll eventually stop, couldn't you then just return; when you have sufficient coverages ?? (i.e. skip creating and evaluating new coverages at that point??).

Comment: Memory is not an issue in my case, because items are checked before adding to the results. I am pretty confident that the list won't exceed a few hundred items.

Comment: Couldn't you also do the upstream kind of like what you've doing - following this pattern `upstream.select().where(f).collect().in(f)` and f is something that implements `BiConsumer` and `Function` [but is stateful - after you've had enough coverages you make sure that the function drops any further elements ...]

Comment: if you only have a few hundred items don't worry about filtering anything out, just return whenvever you've had enough (it'll be called but quickly complete).

Comment: The aforementioned list is the final result.
I may still need to check a lot more items from the stream.
Besides, whether to terminate depends on the content of the list, not on the item.
I would like to terminate, instead of dropping data.
I am seeking a more elegant way to handle such issue in `Multi`.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear .. at the point where your Question is, just return.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official team (https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-mutiny/issues/501), `collect` collects all the items until a terminal event.
I managed to tweak my algorithm to come up with a way to check each item upstream and early terminate using `multi.select().first` API.